# Distributing distinct apples and pears to three people so that each person receives at least one pear

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to distribute seven **distinct** apples and six **distinct** pears to three distinct people such that each person has at least one pear.

Note: The first part of the problem was the same but the word **distinct** was replaced with **identical** apples and pears. That answer is $360$ ways.

What has to be done differently when the word **identical** is replaced with **distinct**?

Answer (score 1):

> How many ways are there to distribute seven identical apples and six identical pears to three distinct people such that each person receives at least one pear?

Let $a_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 3$, be the number of apples given to the $i$th person.  Since there are no restrictions on the number of apples given to each person, 
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 7 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of seven ones.  For instance,
$$1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$, $a_3 = 4$, while 
$$1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $a_1 = 4$, $a_2 = 3$, $a_3 = 0$.  The number of solutions of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers is 
$$\binom{7 + 2}{2} = \binom{9}{2}$$
since we must select which two of the nine positions required for seven ones and two addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Since a particular solution of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k \tag{2}$$
in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ addition signs in a row of $k$ ones, equation 2 has 
$$\binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers since we must select which $n - 1$ of the $k + n - 1$ positions required for $k$ ones and $n - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Let $p_i, 1 \leq i \leq 3$, be the number of pears given to the $i$th person.  Since each person must receive at least one pear,
$$p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 6 \tag{3}$$
is an equation in the positive integers.  A particular solution of equation 3 corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in the five spaces between successive ones in a row of six ones.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, placing addition signs in the second and fifth spaces yields
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1$$
which corresponds to the solution $p_1 = 2$, $p_2 = 3$, $p_3 = 1$.  The number of solutions of equation 3 in the nonnegative integers is 
$$\binom{5}{2}$$
since we must select two of the five spaces between successive ones in a row of six ones in which to place an addition sign.

Since a particular solution of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k \tag{4}$$
in the positive integers corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ addition signs in the $k - 1$ spaces between successive ones in a row of $k$ ones, equation 4 has 
$$\binom{k - 1}{n - 1}$$
solutions in the positive integers.

Hence, the number of ways seven identical apples and six identical pears can be distributed to three distinct people such that each person receives at least one pear is 
$$\binom{9}{2}\binom{5}{2} = 360$$

> How many ways are there to distribute seven distinct apples and six distinct pears to three distinct people such that each person receives at least one pear.

Since there are no restrictions on the number of apples each person receives, they may be distributed in $3^7$ ways since there are three choices of recipient for each of the seven apples.

Since each person receives at least one pear, we must subtract the number of ways of distributing the pears in which fewer than three people receive a pear from the $3^6$ ways the pears could be distributed.

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to exclude one person as a recipient and $2^6$ ways to distribute the six pears to the remaining two people.

However, if we subtract the number of ways of excluding one of the people from being a recipient of a pear, we will have subtracted too much since we will have subtracted those distributions in which two people do not receive a pear twice, once for each way of designating one of them as the person who does not receive a pear.  Thus, we must add those cases back.

There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of excluding two of the people from being recipients of a pear and $1^6$ ways to give all six of the pears to the same person.

Hence, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways of distributing the seven distinct pears so that each person receives at least one is 
$$3^6 - \binom{3}{1}2^6 + \binom{3}{2}1^6$$
so the number of ways of distributing seven distinct apples and six distinct pears to three people such that each person receives at least one pear is 
$$3^7\left[3^6 - \binom{3}{1}2^6 + \binom{3}{2}1^6\right]$$

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130403160806AAzE75W (Part A)...this is also how my professor did it in class.

Comment: i also meant six distinct pears not seven..i just realized the typo. that will probably change part a. my apologis

Comment: While I have updated my answer to reflect the change in the question, you should not change a question after it has been answered since doing so invalidates correct answers to the original question.

Comment: Hi @N.F.Taussig - if you have time, just a question. Am trying to remedy never learning elementary combinatorics as an undergrad (shame!) - hope to build up to the twelvefold way etc however through self study so questions arise. I also used PIE myself but was wondering, is the reason that a naive argument saying $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\cdot 3^{10}$ (choose the pears for the three people then the rest can go wherever) massively overcounts because in some way this designates the 'chosen pear' for each person? That's my suspicion but wanted to check if intuition ok, thanks!

Comment: @Mehness That is correct.  If one person receives five pears, the naive argument you mentioned counts that case five times, once for each way of designating a particular pear that person receives as the pear reserved for that person.  Still worse is the distribution of two pears each to two people and three pears to the third person, which is counted $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 12$ times, once for each way a pear each person receives could be designated as the pear reserved for that person.

Comment: thank you very much indeed that makes sense, filed away for the memory banks :)